# How do I solve the problem of URL not found on the server?

Tags: php, local, host

I am trying to create a simple currency converter with html and php. I have downloaded the MAMP package (local host) on my computer. But when click on the convert button, I get an error : "The requested URL was not found on this server." Can anyone help me find out what is the problem?

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #box
    {
        width:350px;
        height:270px;
        margin:0px auto;
        border:2px solid black;
    }

    h2{
        text-align: center;
    }
    table{
        margin:0px auto;
    }

   </style>
   </head>

  <body>

   <form align="center" action="currencyconvertor.php" method="post">

   <div id="box">

    <h2><center>Currency Converter</center></h2>

    <table>

    <tr>

    <td>

        Enter Amount:<input type="text" name="amount"><br>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

   <td>

    <br><center>From:<select name='cur1'>

     <option value="AUD">Australian Dollar(AUD)</option>

     <option value="USD" selected>US Dollar(USD)</option>

     </select>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

    <td>

    <br><center>To:<select name='cur2'>

     <option value="INR" selected >Indian Rupee(INR)</option>

     <option value="JPY">Japanese Yen(JPY)</option>

     <option value="PHP">Philippine Peso(PHP)</option>
    
    </select>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

    <td><center><br>

    <input type='submit' name='submit' value="CovertNow"></center>

    </td>

    </tr>

    </table>

    </form>

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];

    $cur1 = $_POST['cur1'];

    $cur2 = $_POST['cur2'];

    if($cur1=="AUD" AND $cur2=="JPY"){

    echo "<center><b>Your Converted Amount is:</b><br></center>";

    echo "<center>" . $amount*82.463 . "</center>";

    }





     if($cur1=="AUD" AND $cur2=="INR"){

     echo "<center><b>Your Converted Amount is:</b><br></center>";

     echo "<center>" . $amount* 51.09 . "</center>";

      }


      if($cur1=="AUD" AND $cur2=="PHP"){

      echo "<center><b>Your Converted Amount is:</b><br></center>";

      echo "<center>" . $amount* 37.15 . "</center>";

      }





     if($cur1=="USD" AND $cur2=="JPY"){
     echo "<center><b>Your Converted Amount is:</b><br></center>";
     echo "<center>" . $amount* 109.49 . "</center>";
     }





     if($cur1=="USD" AND $cur2=="INR"){
      echo "<center><b>Your Converted Amount is:</b><br></center>";
      echo "<center>" . $amount* 67.83 . "</center>";
       }





     if($cur1=="USD" AND $cur2=="PHP"){
     echo "<center><b>Your Converted Amount is:</b><br></center>";
      echo "<center>" . $amount*49.32  . "</center>";
      }


      }

      ?>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: 1. Did you check the HTML file and currency converter.php file are stored in the same directory?

2. You can check whether the MAMP server is working properly or not by running localhost in your browser.

Comment: yes, it is the case

Answer (score 0):

It is a **FileNotFoundException** : *currencyconverter.php* doesn't exist (maybe a typo error ?) or is not in the same directory as *index.php*.

I tested your form with *action="#"* to redirect to the same page and it works perfectly, so your problem cannot be anything but the form's action...

[image]

The problem cannot come from MAMP if you are able to generate the first page and to see the form ;)